# Thanks for 1000 tag score on [windbg]

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I was just awarded the golden [windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg) badge for 1000 score. I'm the first user to get this badge and it's my first golden tag badge.

Being the top user on this tag has been very helpful for me and my career. I have sold at least 2 debugging trainings for >5000 € each, *solely* because of Stack Overflow listing me in that high position.

I wanted to thank everyone helping me on my way to understanding WinDbg - even if I can deal with a narrow part of it only (mainly user mode and of that mainly .NET; definitely not kernel).

Thanks

- to Stack Overflow for the great site and bubbling up to the first results on Google
- to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for the great insights and for regularly watching the WinDbg tag, not always answering, but at least commenting short, concise and with an astonishing hit rate. Also of course for various other answers on other people's questions from which I learned a lot.
- to [blabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622813/blabb) for his increasing activity in this tag, compensating my lack of kernel debugging
- to [Marc Sherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317574/marc-sherman) for answering my questions when I didn't know much about WinDbg yet
- to members of the [PyKd team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124839/pykd-team) and/or [PyKd-Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790182/pykd-team) for making scripting easier. One of my solutions for a client used a PyKd script which would otherwise have been almost impossible to solve with WniDbg alone.
- to [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum-reinstate-monica) for various insights and many comments
- to [conio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306930/conio), [snoone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340425/snoone) and [Sean Cline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020072/sean-cline) for being helpful with comments several times even when the question remained unanswered and for correcting me in a friendly and humble way when I was wrong
- to anyone else on Stack Overflow teaching me to ask good questions. It wasn't always very welcoming, but definitely helpful. I can solve a lot of problems myself just because of the ability of thinking how I would describe the problem for Stack Overflow. That's awesome.
- to Microsoft for providing this "ugly" debugger for free.
- to [Steve Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269097/steve-johnson) for providing the useful SOSex extension for analyzing .NET processes even more.
- to [magicandre1981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466046/magicandre1981) answering Bluescreen issues on Super User and posting useful comments here on Stack Overflow.
- to everyone voting on my questions and answers.

A large part of this also made it possible to get my new job as a trainer and pass on my knowledge to students. I love this job and AFAIK, mentioning my SO profile helped me getting it.

Ok, well, this is not a question. And maybe I should have posted it as a comment under the blog post [How This Git Whiz Grew His Career Through Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/10/developer-story-career-jobs-search-success/), but anyway: thanks to all of you.

Comment: Congratulations.  It can be lonely at the top, you lost the right to cast a normal close vote.  Ping me and I'll help.

Comment: @HansPassant are you ... organizing a close voting mob? ;)

Comment: Of course not.  Just helping the guy to avoid getting doxxed when his name is the only one on the close vote banner.  Two is better.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks for that offer. I'm really a bit afraid of using the dupe hammer since I'm not always right with that suggestion. I think I'll post "Related: link" comments instead.

Comment: If you aren’t sure, then a “related link” comment is best. But please don’t be afraid to use the dupehammer when you’re confident. There’s a *reason* we give this power to users with gold tag badges: you’re the most knowledgeable about the subject, and most likely to be able to judge a duplicate. Not sure about WinDBG, but plenty of duplicates are obvious. If users are giving you crap about closing a question, please let a moderator know so we can step in.

Comment: Awesome, how long did that take?

Comment: @JK. probably 6 to 8 years ...

Comment: @JK. I started using WinDbg in 2008 after I had to call Microsoft due to a VB6 runtime corruption. They told me to send a crash dump. I was totally overstrained because I didn't know anything about crash dumps and even less about WinDbg and documentation was harder to find at that time. The Microsoft support engineer was very patient and explained me a lot. I then started to train myself from books (Windows Internals, Advanced Debugging etc.) My first WinDbg tagged answer here on SO was 2010. Around 2011 I started doing debugging workshops myself.

Comment: Congratulations Thomas, in the dark and early days there were not many participants in windbg questions, many people still feel daunted by the tool so I always tried to answer them (althought recently I've kinda stopped answering questions in general) and encourage as many people as possible to use this. You deserve this honour, your answers and comments were useful to me too. Again congratulations